# Geocode calculation - do I have sufficient data?

Tags: mysql, geocode

Please bear with me as I am very new to geocodes and not sure I have what I need to achieve my goal.

I want the user to select a suburb of the city of Melbourne.  When they select the suburb, I want to show the surrounding suburbs within a mile of the one selected.  So, my database table will look like this:

Suburb          LattLong
FITZROY         37° 47' S / 144° 58' E

COLLINGWOOD 37° 48' S / 144° 59' E

ABBOTSFORD  37° 48' S / 144° 59' E

CLIFTON HILL    37° 47' S / 144° 59' E

FITZROY NORTH   37° 47' S / 144° 59' E

CARLTON         37° 48' S / 144° 58' E

So lets say the user selects FITZROY as its suburb.  These are what I think are some of the suburbs within a 1 mile radius.

My problem is that I don't understand the data in the LattLong field.  Is this sufficient data to make my calculation?

Is there an example that would show me how to select the suburbs within 1 mile from a MySQL database?

I have no idea where to begin on google to help me with this so any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,
John

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier to work with geographical data in a database and using mathematical formulas if you convert latitude and longitude to decimal degrees.  This will give you numbers like "80.012345".   You can then write queries based on simple differences of the two numbers, example write a query where the difference of two latitude and longitudes in Decimal degrees are less than 0.02 and so on.

Google decimal degrees to learn more and get the conversion technique. It is a simple formula, you have to also use the E, W. N, and S to assign the decimal number as positive or negative.

In your case you have data only to minutes.  To convert what you have for example, 144° 58' E = 144 + 58/60.  58/60 = 0.9666666666...  However, you only have 2 significant digits - 58 is two sig digits and 60 is two sig digits. So the result is 144.97  Now, in simplified terms a mile is about 0.02 decimal degrees at the equator.  So you need precision to the second decimal place, but you are rounding on this same decimal place.  So your required resolution is at the very limit of the accuracy of the numbers you have.

So, unfortunately, no. Realistically you need at least one more decimal of accuracy to locate things within a mile with any reasonable accuracy.  So you need longitude and latitude with seconds in addition to minutes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  It has made things a lot clearer - exactly what I was looking for except for the insufficient data part :)  I used a website [link](http://www.worldatlas.com/aatlas/latitude_and_longitude_finder.htm)  It seemed ideal because I'm only building the data at the moment.  I don't want it grab the data at runtime but retrieve it from my database.  I had an automated script running that would enter cities and towns then dump them into a database.  I was going to parse the data later on but at least now I know how to convert it to a decimal!  Am on a search now to find..

Comment: another source.  Thanks for your input and found loads on Google regarding decimal degrees so now I have a starting point :)  Cheers!